# Aptana Javascript code assist

Tags: aptana, code-assist

> OS: Ubuntu 11.04 64bit
> Application: Aptana 3.05
> Java: java version "1.6.0_22"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Hi! I'm new to programming, so I decided to not post it as a bug, because I think that should be an easy solution to these problems.
After upgrading to Aptana 3.05, I miss some features and I noticed some strange behaviour.

#### HTML Files Template removed

I accidentally fix it when I opened *command>HTML>Edit this bundle*, than I saved and the application crushed. At restart I had all HTML files template.

A new folder was created Aptana%20Rubles/html.ruble

#### Javascript Code Assistent

It worked so well before updating! now it getting lazy, and seems to have forgot some common methods.

```
function searchList () {
        var txt = document.getElementById("search").value;
        if(!txt){
            alert("Invalid Input");
            document.getElementById("search").focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
document.ge...
```

For instance, the only proposal for the last line is "getElementById"(eg. no -"getElementByTagName")
How can I install or restore a more "basic" javascript assistent?

Even some useful scripts don't work as before. Function in javascript should focus on the function's name, then the function's arguments and finally the body. Instead it skip to the function body after the name.

Do you think a new fresh installation of Aptana 3.05 will fix these issues?
If it won't I rather downgrade.

Comment: The HTML file template bug is noted here: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3597. Regarding the other one about JavaScript....that works for me, though it's "getElementsByTagName" FWIW.

Comment: I just reinstall Aptana(I deleted all rubles too.), again all templates were missing, but by opening/closing the HTML bundle everything come back to normal! I had a problem during the update that's why Javascript was buggy.

Comment: The HTML file templates were just restored which is why reinstalling Aptana 3.0.5 worked. The ticket that @Ingo Muschenetz links to has been closed resolved.